# Adding Amazon S3 ARN Authorization to QGIS

Tags: amazon-s3, gis, config, gdal, qgis

I have a S3 private bucket that grants access to a certain ARN (account value) .I am trying to access the bucket via QGIS though I am unsure on how to use the user variables and/or config files. I have read the GDAL virtual file driver documentation though I am not sure where to specific the Amazon ARN value. Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

I have used the bucket in the browser and the ARN permission works. When I try to connect to the s3 in QGIS via "Add Raster Data source>Http>S3". After specifying the bucket name and object key in QGIS I get an error : This data source is unsupported ....

Anyone experienced this or knows how to add authentication on QGIS when connecting to S3?